# Modify Content in valums file upload plugins after completion of upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, razor

I am using Valums ajax file-upload plugins for multi file-upload using asp.net mvc 3.

**Views**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "AjaxUpload", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "form1", @id="form1" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload Wav File</legend>
         <div class="editor-label">
           @Html.Label("Select Active Date Time")
        </div>
        <div>

        <input type="text" id="active" value="@DateTime.Now" />
      </div>

         <div class="editor-label">
           @Html.Label("Select Language")
        </div>
        <div>
           @Html.DropDownList("Language1", (SelectList)ViewBag.lang)
        </div>
         <div class="editor-label">
           @Html.Label("Select Category")
        </div>
        <div>
           @Html.DropDownList("ParentCategoryID", ViewBag.ParentCategoryID as SelectList) 
        </div>
      <br />
      <div id="file-uploader">
            <noscript>
                <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
            </noscript>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Scripts**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader
    ({
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
        onSubmit: function () {
            uploader.setParams({
                param1: document.getElementById("Language1").value,
                param2: document.getElementById("ParentCategoryID").value,
                param3: document.getElementById("active").value
            });
        },

        action: '@Url.Action("upload")', // put here a path to your page to handle uploading
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'], // user this if you want to upload only pictures
        sizeLimit: 4000000, // max size, about 4MB
        minSizeLimit: 0, // min size
        debug: true
    });

</script>
```

**Controller Action**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase qqfile, string param1, string param2, string param3)
        {
            var filenam = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + param1 + param2 + Request["qqfile"];
            var filename = filenam.Replace(" ", "_");

           var filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), Path.GetFileName(filename));


           if (param2 != null || param2 != "")
           {
               var wav = new PlayWav
               {
                   Name = filename,
                   CategoryID = int.Parse(param2),
                   UserID = repository.GetUserID(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name),
                   LanguageID = int.Parse(param1),
                   UploadDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                   ActiveDateTime = DateTime.Parse(param3),
                   FilePath = filepath
               };

               db.AddToPlayWavs(wav);


               if (qqfile != null)
               {
                   qqfile.SaveAs(filepath);

                   db.SaveChanges();

                   return Json(new { success = true }, "text/html");
               }
               else
               {
                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
                   {

                       using (var output = System.IO.File.Create(filepath))
                       {
                           Request.InputStream.CopyTo(output);
                       }

                       db.SaveChanges();

                       return Json(new { success = true });
                   }
               }
           }
            return Json(new { success = false });
        }
```

**Problems Explaination**
I have Upload controller action where I have rename the filename for uploaded file and it is working fine. The problem here is that after file is uploaded, file name displayed the name of original file name and also show the file size. But I want to display the file name which is re-named and the value which is selected in dropdown box list and datetime value submitted from form fields and it's file size is ok. I have no idea how could I modify those content which is displayed after file-upload is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the new file name is to be returned to clienside as,

assuming filename to be shown is already yielded in the following line,

```
var filenam = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") 
              + param1 + param2 + Request["qqfile"];
```

this needs to be sent to client side,

```
return Json(new { success = true, filename });
```

client side code changes, notice the onCompleted event handler, its job is to replace the original filename with the new one received from server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader
    ({
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
        onSubmit: function () {
            uploader.setParams({
                param1: document.getElementById("Language1").value,
                param2: document.getElementById("ParentCategoryID").value,
                param3: document.getElementById("active").value
            });
        },
        onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJson) {
            $(this.element).find('.qq-upload-list li[qqFileId=' + id + ']').find('.qq-upload-file').html(responseJson.filename);
        },
        action: '@Url.Action("upload")', // put here a path to your page to handle uploading
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'], // user this if you want to upload only pictures
        sizeLimit: 4000000, // max size, about 4MB
        minSizeLimit: 0, // min size
        debug: true
    });

</script>
```

hope this helps.

EDIT:

qqFileId attribute in the li element is the only associating link bitween the informative li item and uploaded files.
Though the qqFileId is not visible in firebug dom structure, in the console executing the following command shows the id,

```
$('.qq-upload-list li:last').attr('qqFileId')
```

if ie browser is causing you the problem it might be because of,

```
find('.qq-upload-list li[qqFileId=' + id + ']')
```

and can be changed as

```
onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJson) {
    $(this.element).find('.qq-upload-list li').each(function () {
        if($(this).attr('qqFileId')==id)
            $(this).find('.qq-upload-file').html(responseJson.filename);
    });
}
```

Comment: `find('.qq-upload-list li[qqFileId=' + id + ']')` this may be to associate corresponding list that does not works and remove qqFileId and it shows renamed filename. In firebug looks for **qqFileId** could not found so I deleted that code but it modify all li list when uploading new file. Would you please tell me what might be problem.

Comment: qqFileId attribute in the li element is the only associating link bitween li and uploaded files.
it may notvisible in firebug, the firebug console executing the following, shows the id, $('.qq-upload-list li:last').attr('qqFileId').
if ie causing you the problem it might be because of, 
"find('.qq-upload-list li[qqFileId='+id+']')", and can be changed to

onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJson) {
    $(this.element).find('.qq-upload-list li').each(function () {
        if($(this).attr('qqFileId')==id)
            $(this).find('.qq-upload-file').html(responseJson.filename);
    });
}